Meromorphic function takes each value of the Riemann sphere the same number of times
Let $f$ be a nonconstant meromorphic function on the Riemann sphere $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$. How do I show that $f$ takes each value in $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ the same number of times (counting multiplicity)?
My work so far: by the generalized argument principle, it follows that $f$ must have as many zeroes as poles. The book I'm reading (Problem 1.3.8 of Geomety of the Quintic by Jerry Shurman) promises that this is sufficient to prove the original claim, but I don't see how.

If you already know that a nonconstant meromorphic function on the Riemann sphere  has as many zeros as poles then you can argue as follows:
For any $a \in \Bbb C$ is
$$
\begin{align}
 &\text{number of $a$-points of $f$, counting multiplicity} \\
&\quad = \text{number of zeros of $f-a$, counting multiplicity} \\
&\quad = \text{number of poles of $f-a$, counting multiplicity} \\
&\quad = \text{number of poles of $f$, counting multiplicity} \, .
\end{align}
$$
